# Firebase for unity crashes

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

After updating my game, Firebase crashes. I upgrade first to the last version 5.4.0 but still got the same error. I downgrade to 5.2.0 but nothing change. On my console, using adb logcat, I have :

```
11-04 01:37:37.420  1318  1333 W HwPolicyFactoryImpl: mAware is disable
11-04 01:37:37.462 12161 12308 E Unity   : DllNotFoundException: FirebaseCppApp-5.2.0
11-04 01:37:37.462 12161 12308 E Unity   :   at (wrapper managed-to-native) Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper:SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_AppUtil (Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate)
11-04 01:37:37.462 12161 12308 E Unity   :   at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
11-04 01:37:37.462 12161 12308 E Unity   : Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initialize
11-04 01:37:37.792  1318  1478 E WifiConfigManager: updateConfiguration freq=2467 BSSID=14:0c:**:**:fa:dc RSSI=-66 "TuNeTeConnecterasPas"WPA_PSK
11-04 01:37:38.188  1318  1542 E HwCHRWifiRSSIGroupSummery: updatArpSummery mRSSI:-66  HwCHRWifiRSSIGroup [rssi_index=3, rtt_tcp_packets=824, rtt_tcp_duration=58535, rtt_lan_duration=3215, rtt_lan_failures=0, rtt_lan_succ=161, rtt_lan_max=73, rtt_lan_min=4,same_area_frequency=0,adjacent_area_frequency=0]
11-04 01:37:38.401  1318  1318 I TrafficMonitor: expired arrive. level:-1
11-04 01:37:38.401  1318  1318 I TrafficMonitor: during_ms:2001,period_ms:2000
```

Please could you know how could I correct it ?
I use unity 2018, jdk8, target android 27.

Comment: Are the plugin DLL files set to be included in your Android build?

Comment: @RetiredNinja normally yes. The plugin is set to be used without modification or adding extra DLL

Comment: What I meant was that in the inspector you can choose the platforms that a dll or other plugin file is included in. That information is stored in the meta file. Sometimes if you install a package over an older or newer version that information is lost and you need to set it again. You might try completely removing the plugin from your project and then installing it again.